# Confide in or confide to

Tags: prepositions

I usually say

- I confided my doubt *to* Mr X.
- You can confide *in* me.

But I have seen a sentence

```
You should not confide *to*  stranger.
```

Is the above sentence right or should we replace *confide to* with *confide in*
Can anyone enlighten me where to use *in* and *to* with confide.

Answer (score 3):

Both "confide in" and "confide to" are used, but they differ in meaning and their placement in a sentence.

But it is worth mentioning that the phrasal verb "confide" usually goes with the preposition "in", and it is actually an idiom. Here [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=confide+in%2Cconfide+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconfide%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconfide%20to%3B%2Cc0) shows that.

"Confide in [someone]" means:

> To trust someone with one's secrets or personal matters.

"Confide [something] in/to [someone]" means:

> To tell a secret or private matter to someone, trusting that the person will not reveal the secret.

[*The Free Dictionary*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/confide+to)

Now, back to your examples:

1- *I confided my secrets
to Mr X.*

This should be written like this:

> I confided my doubt to Mr.X.

It means you told X, whom you trust, a private matter.

2- *You can confide in me.*

This simply means you can trust me.

3- *You should not confide to stranger.*

This should be written, in order to be totally correct:

> a) You should not confide anything to a stranger.

> b) You should not confide anything to strangers.

> c) You should not confide in strangers.

They are all possible, but each one has a different meaning.

(a)+(b) means you shouldn't tell anything secretive or private to {a stranger / strangers}.

(c) means you shouldn't trust strangers generally.

In this example, "confide to" can be used alone, but it would be possible if it was followed by something as it means **tell** more than **trust**. So, you need a speech to actually talk about to that stranger.

---

I didn't find a definition for "Confide to" except when [something] is placed between the verb and its preposition, but here's a sentence where you can use it:

> She **confided to** her friend **that she smoked** cigarettes last night.

With "confide in", it will become:

> She **confided in** her friend **about smoking** cigarettes last night.